# Forming a Grid With a JS Matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix

A friend and I are making a God-like Game for the browser. It is VERY early stages, but I already have problems with my code!

It was suggested by someone on Stack Overflow to use a 'matrix' (I think that is what he called it) for organizing the tiles that you can build on. I now have a system for reading and editing the contents of a tile, but I am not sure how I can lay out the matrix in a grid format like this:

- tile 1, tile 2, tile 3
- tile 4, tile 5, tile 6
- tile 7, tile 8, tile 9

It would be ideal if this would work no matter how many rows and columns there were.

Here is my code so far:

```
var WoodHut = "Woodcutter's hut";
var TownHall = "TownHall";
var Mine = "Iron Mine";

var tiles = [];
var rowCount = 15;
var columnCount = 15;

// Assign the none string to all tiles.
for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
{
    tiles[r] = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
    {
        var currentRow = tiles[r];
        currentRow[c] = "--none--";
    }
}
// NOTE TO SELF: Arrays are 0-based!
// access row 4, column 2.
// console.log(tiles[3][1]);

// Assign something to row 5 column 3.
// tiles[4][2] = WoodHut

function Build(locX, locY, type){
    this.locX = X
    this.locY = Y
    this.type = type;
    tiles[X][Y] = type;
}

function TownMap(){
    // HOW DO I DO THIS???????
    }
```

So in summary, I want to be able to call `TownMap()` and have a grid of tile values displayed in an alert or a console log.

Any Feedback would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wow I'm doing the same thing, only that I started 2 weeks ago.
Any way we could get in contact?

I'll show you how I did the grid:

```
function setup() {
  // Create Grid
  var grid = $('#grid');
  for (var i = 0; i < tileCount; i++) {
    var tile = document.createElement('div');
    tile.id = "t" + (i + 1);
    tile.className = "tile";
    tile.onclick = function () {
      deselect();
      activeTile = $(this);
      $(this).addClass("active");
      tilePopup(this);
    };
    grid.append(tile);
  }

  //Create Menu
  var menu = $('#menu');
  for (var i = 0; i < buildings; i++) {
    var building = document.createElement('div');
    building.id = "b" + (i + 1);
    //building.className = "building";
    building.innerHTML = "Building " + (i + 1);
    building.style.background = "url('images/buildings/" + building.id + ".png') 0 26px / 100% auto no-repeat";
    building.onclick = function () {
      build(this.id);
    };
    menu.append(building);
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
#grid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  left: 400px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
  background-image: url("images/ground.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.tile {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  outline: 1px ridge rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.8);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i am a complete novice with this kind of thing so it would be great if you could talk me through it step by step!

Comment: Got it, you can delete the email now ;)